# Azure Service Fabric (OneBox) has constantly failed DnsService

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am using the OneBox of Azure Service Fabric on my development machine to develop a service fabric application. No matter what I do, the fabric:/System/DnsService always has an error. The service is listed in the Service Fabric Explorer in the following way...

```
(error) System
    (error) fabric:/System/DnsService
        (error) f47a6d0d-3919-4683-9f79-747b61d8ce2b
            (warning) _Node_0
```

Selecting the _Node_0 entry has the following warning...

```
Unhealthy event: 
    SourceId='System.FabricDnsService', 
    Property='Socket', 
    HealthState='Warning', 
    ConsiderWarningAsError=false.

    DnsService UDP listener is unable to start. Please make sure there are
    no processes listening on the DNS port 53. List of processes listening
    on the DNS port:

        UDP   0.0.0.0:53   *:*   7472
```

I have rebooted the machine, I have 'Reset Local Cluster', I have switched to and from the '5 Node' setup. Nothing changes the fact the DnsService constantly has the above issue. Any ideas?

Comment: My problem was caused by the ICS service. You can read about it more here: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/796

Comment: Thanks, I definitely had that problem in the past as well. Since I posted the question I downloaded the latest SDK (6.3.187.9494) and not it seems to work fine. So I think it was a version issue.

Comment: @PhilWright it was an issue with version 6.1 as noted in the link posted by Peter