# Azure Service Fabric local deployment results in DnsService error: DnsService UDP listener is unable to start

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

### The Problem

I am developing an Azure Service Fabric stateless service. While I have deployed locally before, I am currently encountering the following error:

```
DnsService UDP listener is unable to start. Please make sure there are no processes listening on the DNS port 53.
```

[image: DnsService error]

### Things I have tried

- Redeploying locally
- Both stopping and resetting the cluster from the tray menu
- Removing the cluster from my machine
- Checking to make sure the cluster manifest has the `DnsService` parameter `IsEnabled` set to `True`
- Starting a new application from scratch
- [Azure Service Fabric (OneBox) has constantly failed DnsService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000864/azure-service-fabric-onebox-has-constantly-failed-dnsservice) has not provided a solution

Edit:

- [Stopping and disabling the ICS service](https://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Internet-Connection-Sharing) isn't helpful in my case because ICS restarts when I restart my machine.

### Other relevant info

I *can* deploy successfully to an Azure cluster, so I am fairly certain that the problem lies in the local cluster. But removing the cluster and redeploying does not solve the error!

### How do I solve this DnsService error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I uninstalled Docker** per [@Taran's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50358973/5587356) answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364004/microsoft-service-fabric-host-service-fabrichostsvc-hangs-on-start/50358973#50358973). This was the most resilient answer as I was then able to deploy successfully x 10. :-)

Comment: Note: I used [@HaveNoDisplayName's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302848/5587356) to [How should I address a question/answer that indirectly answered another question without it being asked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302847/how-should-i-address-a-question-answer-that-indirectly-answered-another-question) to figure out how to handle referencing [@Taran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50358973/5587356)

Answer (score 3):

As the error message suggests:

`Please make sure there are no processes listening on the DNS port 53.`

From the error message show in the screenshot you provided, is it possible to see other services are listening on the port 53, for that reason the service does not work.

[This github issue](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/796) describe the problem.

In summary, the problem is likely to be the ***Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) service*** or other service listening on port 53. You have to stop these services to make DNS service work correctly.

To find out the service using the port 53, you can follow the answer from this question: 
[How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Comment: [Instructions for disabling ICS](https://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Internet-Connection-Sharing)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, this answer does not solve my problem for the reasons explained by user jupsij in GitHub issue #796. Namely, ICS restarts when I restart my machine.